# Slide Toggle в нескольких блоках

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Есть такая верстка

```
<button class="btn_more">Подробнее</button></p>

<div class="ctn_more">Первый блок</div>

<button class="btn_more">Подробнее</button></p>

<div class="ctn_more">Второй блок</div>

<button class="btn_more">Подробнее</button></p>

<div class="ctn_more">Третий блок</div>
```

Работает slideToogle

```
<script>
$(".btn_more").click(function () {
      $(".ctn_more").slideToggle("slow");
    });

</script>
```

Но он открывает сразу все? как написать что бы открывал блок той кнопки по которой нажал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".btn_more").click(function() {
  $(this).next("div.ctn_more").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn_more">Подробнее</button>
<div class="ctn_more">Первый блок</div>

<button class="btn_more">Подробнее</button>
<div class="ctn_more">Второй блок</div>

<button class="btn_more">Подробнее</button>
<div class="ctn_more">Третий блок</div>
```